# Pulling top results with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, html, google-chrome, selenium, xpath

I am trying to enter a search term and get list of the top urls back from the search. I'm brand new to Selenium and don't know exactly what I'm doing. So far, I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EELySnTPeyw&t=21s

Everything works up until returning the top urls. The xPath that I am using is straight from the element on google after inspection. This is my current code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_results(search_term):
    url = "https://www.google.com"

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("lst-ib")
    search_box.send_keys(search_term)
    search_box.submit()

    links = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="rso"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3/a")

    results = []
    for link in links:
        href = link.get_attribute("href")
        print(href)
        results.append(href)

    driver.close()
    return results


get_results("Who is the president of the united states?")
```

When running this I keep getting an Invalid Syntax Error on the xPath `("//*[@id="rso"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3/a")`. Any ideas on why this isn't working? Thanks

Comment: If you want to get `list` of elements, you should use `find_elements_by_xpath()` instead of `find_element_by_xpath()`

Answer (score 1):

Remember you SHOULD use String in `find_element_by_xpath`.

so you can change

`"//*[@id="rso"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3/a"`

to

`"//*[@id='rso']/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3/a"`

so It can be all String.

Comment: I tried this and it is still showing this error: `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='rso']/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h3/a"}`

Comment: This is another issue, this shows that element selected by XPath.
How about using CSS Selector Instead?

Comment: You can use CSS Selector by `find_elements_by_css_selector`

Comment: It's still showing that same error, only with the css selector path instead. I think I may just use python Requests instead of Selenium. I've heard that's better anyways. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You use this xpath:

> ("//*[@id='rso']//h3/a")

And you should use find_elements_by_xpath to get results as a list object.
find_element_by_xpath returns only first element.

```
find_element(s)_by_xpath
```

Comment: Whenever I change fin_element to `find_elements` the function does not work. Chrome will open and then immediately close. And I tried the xpath you mentioned, for some reason it is still returning an error for no such element

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="rso"]/div/div/div/div/div/h3/a""")
```

The explanation is that URLs xpaths are not following a pattern, so when this happens you just have to delete the `[n]` of the path that is causing the error.